# Filter emails in Gmail by number of messages in a conversation

Tags: gmail

I want to search Gmail and bring up conversations that have only a certain number of messages in the thread.

Say I want to see a thread that has more than three messages in it. Is there a way to filter and show these conversations by how many messages are in it?

Answer (score 13):

[Gmail advanced filters](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=7190) help indicates that there is no way to filter by number of messages in a conversation.

Answer (score 5):

I've been thinking about this for nearly 5 years now and it finally hit me.

You can't. Not in Gmail. But you can install an email client such as Thunderbird, sort the mails by subject, and then you can see the number of messages in a 'thread', [IYCMD](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=IYCMD).

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't filter by number of emails, but in some circumstances it may help to be able to filter by size:

Search for emails above 1kb (1000 bytes)

```
size:1000
```

Or above 1mb (1000000 bytes)

```
size:1000000
```

Answer (score 0):

I didnt find a way to search for a certain NUMBER of messages BUT....

from:me to:*

Will return all sent emails which does show threads that were active. It will also show emails you sent that were unanswered

Answer (score -3):

I encountered this problem when I tried to sort out a zillion of promotion emails in my inbox from the important emails. The **from:me label:inbox** filter for some reason did not work, so I thought the most natural solution was to filter emails with a single message in a conversation. This happened to be impossible too.

Finally, I starred all sent emails and applied **is:starred is:inbox**. That worked.